# Remove Column Names in the output

Tags: python, sql

I want to read data from MySQL database, and here's my code:

```
def create_server_connection(host, user, password,db):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                     user=user,
                                     password=password,
                                     database=db,
                                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        print("MySQL Database connection successful")
    except err as error:
        print(f"Error: '{error}'")
    return connection

connection = create_server_connection("localhost", "root", "root1234","raw_data")
cur = connection.cursor()

def get_Tables_byName(cursor, tableName):
    q1 = f'''
    SELECT * FROM raw_data.{tableName}; '''
    res = []
    cursor.execute(q1)
    for row in cursor:
        res.append(row)
    return res

results = get_Tables_byName(cur,'data_31942010201')
print(results)
```

One of lines of the output is {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 9}. How do I remove the variable names so that the output becomes {3, 6, 9}?

[Sample rows from "raw_data.{tableName}"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0MKb.jpg)

Part of the output:

[{'IMU_sample_rate': 500.0, 'grf_sample_rate': 1000.0, 'lshank_time': None, 'lshank_accel_x': None, 'lshank_accel_y': None, 'lshank_accel_z': None, 'lshank_gyro_x': None, 'lshank_gyro_y': None, 'lshank_gyro_z': None, 'lshank_mag_x': None, 'lshank_mag_y': None, 'lshank_mag_z': None, 'lshank_quat_x': None, 'lshank_quat_y': None, 'lshank_quat_z': None, 'rshank_time': None, 'rshank_accel_x': None, 'rshank_accel_y': None, 'rshank_accel_z': None, 'rshank_gyro_x': None, 'rshank_gyro_y': None, 'rshank_gyro_z': None, 'rshank_mag_x': None, 'rshank_mag_y': None, 'rshank_mag_z': None, 'rshank_quat_x': None, 'rshank_quat_y': None, 'rshank_quat_z': None, 'sacrum_time': None, 'sacrum_accel_x': None, 'sacrum_accel_y': None, 'sacrum_accel_z': None, 'sacrum_gyro_x': None, 'sacrum_gyro_y': None, 'sacrum_gyro_z': None, 'sacrum_mag_x': None, 'sacrum_mag_y': None, 'sacrum_mag_z': None, 'sacrum_quat_x': None, 'sacrum_quat_y': None, 'sacrum_quat_z': None, 'grf_time': 177.6229999943701, 'grf_x': -1.2485357103999917, 'grf_y': 3.549862406599999, 'grf_z': 642.777432292, 'grf_fp1_ax': None, 'grf_fp1_ay': None, 'grf_fp2_ax': None, 'grf_fp2_ay': None}, {'IMU_sample_rate': 500.0, 'grf_sample_rate': 1000.0, 'lshank_time': None, 'lshank_accel_x': None, 'lshank_accel_y': None, 'lshank_accel_z': None, 'lshank_gyro_x': None, 'lshank_gyro_y': None, 'lshank_gyro_z': None, 'lshank_mag_x': None, 'lshank_mag_y': None, 'lshank_mag_z': None, 'lshank_quat_x': None, 'lshank_quat_y': None, 'lshank_quat_z': None, 'rshank_time': None, 'rshank_accel_x': None, 'rshank_accel_y': None, 'rshank_accel_z': None, 'rshank_gyro_x': None, 'rshank_gyro_y': None, 'rshank_gyro_z': None, 'rshank_mag_x': None, 'rshank_mag_y': None, 'rshank_mag_z': None, 'rshank_quat_x': None, 'rshank_quat_y': None, 'rshank_quat_z': None, 'sacrum_time': None, 'sacrum_accel_x': None, 'sacrum_accel_y': None, 'sacrum_accel_z': None, 'sacrum_gyro_x': None, 'sacrum_gyro_y': None, 'sacrum_gyro_z': None, 'sacrum_mag_x': None, 'sacrum_mag_y': None, 'sacrum_mag_z': None, 'sacrum_quat_x': None, 'sacrum_quat_y': None, 'sacrum_quat_z': None, 'grf_time': 177.624, 'grf_x': -1.382789665600015, 'grf_y':
3.6822509309999916, 'grf_z': 642.082102484, 'grf_fp1_ax': None, 'grf_fp1_ay': None, 'grf_fp2_ax': None, 'grf_fp2_ay': None}]

Comment: Try with `print(results.values)`.

Comment: It says the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: can you share sample rows from "*raw_data.{tableName}*" and your full output?

Comment: Yes. I will post them in the original post. Thank you!

Comment: print(results[0].values)

Comment: please can you share where does `{'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 9}` appear in your output?

Comment: thank you! The output of print(results[0].values) says <built-in method values of dict object at 0x10e8b8740>

Comment: Sorry {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 9} is  just an example, I simplified the output just for easy-reading purpose.

Comment: Try this but it will change the order `set(results.values())`

Comment: Thank you! set(results.values()) shows the error of AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary cursor if you don't want the rows to be returned as dictionaries? Default cursors return tuples.

Comment: try usinf fetchall which shpur return a tuple with only the values

Comment: I used fetchall() but still has the same output

Comment: see @Barmar comment, you set the cursor to dictionary i don't know where in your code

Comment: @nbk I have uploaded where I set cursor in my code, but I don't think I set a dictionary cursor though

Comment: @Tan see your connection string remove `,
                                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor`